# Creating duplicate files while pushing the changes

Tags: git

I did some changes in my code and tried to push the changes to master and while doing so it created the duplicate files(files are already there created with new name as 1 extended to it. Like, if name is project duplicate file name will be project1).My question is how to remove duplicate files? Why duplicate file is creating while pushing my changes.
Used gitbash for code push.
Followed commands:
1.created branch from master
2. Did changes in code
3.merge in to master

Comment: If you want an answer it might be a good idea to ask a question. What do you want to know?

Comment: Would prefer if you provide more details like what exact commands and parameters you used. And what steps you followed?

Answer (score 0):

Unless the remote repository has some bizarre hook, the creation of xxx.1 file is enterely:

- on your (client) local side
- done by a tool (like an editor making automatic backup copy)

Git alone would not create duplicate files.
A `git add .`/`git status`/`git commit -m "my work"`/`git push` would not create *additional* files.

Answer (score 0):

I can imagine two possibilities :

1). Your editor is creating backup copies as mentioned in above answer.
For this, create any random file in any random folder (anywhere, even outside the git repository) and check if duplicate file is being created.

2) There are some git hooks configured and you are not aware. 
To check this, you should follow these steps:

1. Check at which steps files are being created:

   a. Before commit

   b. After commit and before push

   c. After push
2. Based on your question, for now I am assuming it is being created before push.
3. Execute following command to check if there are any pre-push hook configured:

```
ls .git/hooks/pre-push
```

4. If above command returns result then check the .git/hooks/pre-push file and make sure there is nothing in this script which copies file and create duplicate files before you push changes.

Comment: Thanks Rajni...Creating before push

Comment: Great @Devi. That means you can check pre-push script as explained in my answer.